# Quão comum é o som do R americano em português?

Tags: português-brasileiro, fonologia, dialetos

Tecnicamente, o R do inglês americano não é um som, há mais de um R, mas é mais fácil de explicar assim. Estarei falando dos Rs em "Right" e "Room".

A regra é "r" no final de palavras ou antes de consoantes — nunca em início de palavras —, "poRta" e "falaR", porém o R em "falar a ideia" é vibrado (como em "paRa"). Outra regra é que todo R americano pode ser pronunciado como R vibrado ("paRA") — Como meu avô. A maioria, onde vivo, não fala assim, mas existe e é totalmente possível e não errado.

Já ouvi que tem história nos índios: não tinham este som, mas tinham o R americano, então falavam assim.

Sei que há dois Rs americanos: /ɹ/ e /ɻ/ (Alfabeto Fonético Internacional).

Com tudo isto em mente, quão comum é a pronúncia deste(s) R(s)? Se possível, qual a(s) sua(s) história?

Comment: Devias incluir na pergunta um par de palavras inglesas que tenham esse "R americano" que referes. Ou um par de palavras para cada um dos "R" que queres referir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O R americano é utilizado em português apenas no meio das palavras, nunca no início ou antes de vogais. Seu uso é limitado antes de consoantes e no meio ou final de palavras.Exemplos: Bar, Carta, Porta.
A pronúncia varia conforme regionalismos (sotaques), sendo o R "americano" estrito falado somente nas regiões do interior dos estados do sul/sudeste (Paraná, São Paulo). Dá para calcularmos que menos de 50 % dos brasileiros têm esta pronúncia.

As variantes do uso do R são uma das principais formas de diferenciação sotaque.
No Rio de Janeiro, usa-se o R mais ou menos como o h inglês e j castelhano. 'O povo chama esta espécie do r de "r puxado".
Palavras como RISCO, RATO, todas utilizam o R vibrado, ou o R "não americano".
As duas maiores marcas registradas de falantes não nativos de português são o uso incorreto dos gêneros (já que na língua inglesa não existe variante de gênero masculino e feminino para objetos) e a pronúncia do R americano antes de vogais.
Ao meu ver aquele falante não-nativo do português que quiser aperfeiçoar sua pronúncia ao nível da excelência deve trabalhar muito na pronúncia do R "brasileiro" e nas conjugações de gêneros de objetos inanimados.

Comment: Só passando pra corrigir que esse R americano é genuinamente brasileiro.

Comment: Principalmente pra quem é do interiorrr... do Paraná ou SP:  A porrrca passou pela porrta.  :D